# Convert to async await

Tags: async-await

I am trying to figure out how to make the following piece of code use await. Could someone give me an example of how it should look like and the logic behind it?

```
    const makeReq = (options) =>{
        let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            pm.sendRequest(options, (error, response) => {
                console.log('response: ',response.json())
                if(error){
                    console.log('error:',error);
                }
                if(!error){
                    resolve(response.json());
                }
                else{
                    reject(error);
                }
            });
        });

        return promise;
    }
    
    const asyncReq = async (options) =>{

        return makeReq(options)
        
        .then(res =>{
            return res;
        })

        .catch(err => {
            console.warn('errors ending req ',err);
        })
    }

    let libraryExport = {
        checkResponseBody,
        asyncReq
    };

    return libraryExport;
   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s start with the `async` keyword. It can be placed before a function, like this:

```
async function f() {
  return 1;
}
```

The word `async` before a function means one simple thing: a function always returns a promise. Other values are wrapped in a resolved promise automatically.

For instance, this function returns a resolved promise with the result of 1; let’s test it:

```
async function f() {
  return 1;
}

f().then(alert); // 1
```

We could explicitly return a promise, which would be the same:

```
async function f() {
  return Promise.resolve(1);
}

f().then(alert); // 1
```

So, `async` ensures that the function returns a promise, and wraps non-promises in it. Simple enough, right? But not only that. There’s another keyword, `await`, that works only inside `async` functions, and it’s pretty cool.

AWAIT :
The keyword `await` makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles and returns its result.
Here’s an example with a promise that resolves in 1 second:

```
async function f() {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });
  let result = await promise; // wait until the promise resolves (*)
  alert(result); // "done!"
}
f();
```

ERROR HANDLING :
If a promise resolves normally, then `await` promise returns the result. But in the case of a rejection, it throws the error, just as if there were a throw statement at that line.

```
async function f() {
  await Promise.reject(new Error("Whoops!"));
}
```

CONCLUSION
The `async` keyword before a function has two effects:

Makes it always return a promise.
Allows `await` to be used in it.
The `await` keyword before a promise makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles, and then:

If it’s an error, the exception is generated — same as if throw error were called at that very place.
Otherwise, it returns the result.
Together they provide a great framework to write asynchronous code that is easy to both read and write.

With `async`/`await` we rarely need to write `Promise.then`/`catch`, but we still shouldn’t forget that they are based on promises, because sometimes (e.g. in the outermost scope) we have to use these methods. Also `Promise.all` is nice when we are waiting for many tasks simultaneously.

Comment: So thoroughly explained, thanks a lot! Will try to figure out how to convert it using this.